# How can i send a parameter to be used in the @PostConstruct method of a backing bean?

Tags: jsf

I need to preload some data to be displayed when the page loads. The initialization steps are performed on a @PostConstruct-annotated method but now i need to use a parameter in order to get the data.

What i'm trying to do:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init()
{
   List data = getDataFromDB(parameter) /*Need to read a parameter created somewhere else*/
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Where does this parameter come from?

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of hard to say what you mean by "a parameter set somewhere else". I will assume that "somewhere else" means "sent from browser by HTTP". In such case you should create a standard property in your managed bean and:

- in JSF 2.0 you could annotate it with @ManagedProperty("#{param.nameOfParameterToRead}")
- in JSF 1.2 and less - use managed-property element in your bean description (faces-config.xml).

Like this:

```
    @ManagedBean
    @RequestScoped
    class MyManagedBean {
```

```
   @ManagedProperty("#{param.id}")
   public Integer id;

   @PostConstruct
   public void init(){
     data = getDataFromDB(id)
   }



// setters and getters (mandatory, even though annotation is on an attribute!!!)


}
```

Careful: injecting properties does not use JSF converters, so it is best to inject strings and take care of conversion in your own code.

Comment: It functions not in view scoped beans.

Comment: @lechlukasz: that is a totally different thing. The rule of JSF managed beans is that you can't inject things into wider scopes, so since params bean is request-scoped, it cannot be injected into view- or session- or application-scoped beans.

Comment: @lechlukasz: the standard answer is to use <f:event> in <f:metadata> and listen to PreRenderView. Then, in the listener, check if this is a postback (going through facescontext -> externalcontext). Since the check is ugly, you can use one of libraries that give you a "view action" tag. Like Seam. Or the great Omnifaces. Or the current build of JSF 2.2, where you get a viewaction tag, that does exactly what you want.

Comment: Yes, I've found that in the answer of BallusC. Unfortunatelly I have to live with that isPostback workaround... it's still better than having isInitialized flag in bean.

Comment: @lechlukasz: no matter what, do yourself a favor and try Omnifaces. It's a library by BallusC and it is practically a "set of drop-in solutions for every JSF problem that people have asked on Stackoverflow and BallusC answered", which is probably equal to "every JSF problem on earth". Small, lean, invisible.

Answer (score 0):

how about reading from `Properties` file, or fetching `List` from DB ??

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```java
private (YourTypeForData) data;

@Value("${prop.file.val.id}")
private void setData(int id){
    data = getDataFromDB(id)
}
```