# JSF2 pass an attribute to backing bean on page load

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, pageload, backing-beans, postconstruct

I have two different JSF2 pages with a shared backing bean. How can I pass a parameter from page to the backing bean (on page load - method with @PostConstruct) so that it knows which page is currently being used.

I know it's possible to use an `<f:event>` like `preRenderView` (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341462/initializng-a-backing-bean-with-parameters-on-page-load-with-jsf-2-0)), but it then requires a method as well as a field in the backing bean. Is this possible with something like f:attribute or f:param, without any extra method in the backing bean?

Comment: Seel this link for passing parameter using @PostConstruct http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673844/how-can-i-send-a-parameter-to-be-used-in-the-postconstruct-method-of-a-backing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the bean is request scoped, just get the view ID as managed property by `#{view.viewId}`.

```
@ManagedProperty("#{view.viewId}")
private String viewId; // +setter
```

If the bean is view scoped, just get the view ID directly by [`UIViewRoot#viewId()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIViewRoot.html#getViewId%28%29).

```
private String viewId;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    viewId = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewId();
    // ...
}
```